# Git submodule codecommit

Tags: git, amazon-web-services, git-submodules, aws-codecommit

I have two repositories in AWS Codecommit and I want to add the one repo as submodule into the other repositories.
The two repos are located in a role, not in the root account

.gitmodules (File in Repo1)

```
[submodule "submodule"]
path = sub/module
url = codecommit://Repo2
```

With

```
git submodule update
```

I get

```
fatal: transport 'codecommit' not allowed
fatal: clone of 'codecommit://Repo2' into submodule path 'sub/module' failed
```

And I cannot use the HTTPS because I don't know how to switch a role with HTTPS.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The secret is to configure git to always use the transport

```
git config --global --add protocol.codecommit.allow always
```